# The junction tree theorem

Tags: inference, graphical-model

In [1] (Page 31,equation 2.12 ) it is claiming that in a graph which is processed by the junction tree algorithm, the joint distribution of the variables could be found by 
$$
p(x_1, ..., x_m) = \frac{ \prod_{C \in \mathcal{C}} \mu_{C}(x_C) }{  \prod_{S \in \mathcal{S}} [\mu_{S}(x_S)]^{d(S)-1}  }
$$
In which $d(S)$ denote the number of maximal cliques to which it is adjacent.
The problem is that, I don't really see where this distribution is coming from. Any ideas?

[1] http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, observe that, all of the factors include all of the variables and their joint distributions. But they have more factors. In particular, each variable inside one separator $S$ is repeated $d(S)$ times inside the neighbouring  factors. That's why the distribution is normalized by dividing by the separators to the power of $d(S)$.